# Remove a css class for textbox on focus event using javascript without using jquery

Tags: javascript

Am trying to remove "error-border" class for input fields in my form. i need to done it with javascript without using jquery, in 'Onfocus event' of each input field. Please help me to solve this

I have tried following code

```
document.getElementsByClassName("error-class").focus({
document.getElementsByClassName("error-class").remove();
});
```

Please help me to solve this

Comment: See the linked question's answers and [basic event handling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener). You might also look into [event delegation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1688293/157247).

Comment: `document.querySelector('input[type="text"]').addEventListener('focus', function(event) {  this.classList.remove("error-class"); });`

Comment: I wasn't entirely happy with the delegation answers there, so [I added one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55452921/157247).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it like this.

```
var error = document.getElementsByClassName("error-class");

error.onfocus = function(){
  error.classList.remove('error-class');
}
```

Comment: Its giving error, i want to remove error border of each of the form elements error class in  on focus

Comment: It would be great if you could post your entire code including the CSS , So can see what is happening in the code

Comment: So when you focus on the "error-class" , You want to remove the "error-border" class ?

Comment: Yes, i want it do for each of the form fields in on focus event